# AWS CLI - Put output into a readable format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I have ran the following command in my CLI and it returned values, however, they are unreadable how would I format this into a table with a command?

> do
> echo "Check if SSE is enabled for bucket -> ${i}"
> aws s3api get-bucket-encryption --bucket ${i}  | jq -r .ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration.Rules[0].ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault.SSEAlgorithm
> done

Would I need to change the command above?

Comment: --output text or json.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an `--output` parameter when using the AWS CLI, or configure a default format using the `aws configure` command.

From [Setting the AWS CLI output format - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output-format.html):

> The AWS CLI supports the following output formats:
>
> **json** – The output is formatted as a JSON string.
>
> **yaml** – The output is formatted as a YAML string.
>
> **yaml-stream** – The output is streamed and formatted as a YAML string. Streaming allows for faster handling of large data types.
>
> **text** – The output is formatted as multiple lines of tab-separated string values. This can be useful to pass the output to a text processor, like grep, sed, or awk.
>
> **table** – The output is formatted as a table using the characters +|- to form the cell borders. It typically presents the information in a "human-friendly" format that is much easier to read than the others, but not as programmatically useful.